# Activating text editing macros on Netbeans

Tags: macos, mac, macros, netbeans

Ok, I've been using Netbeans on Mac OS X for sometime it has some really good features but it doesn't support most of the macros and that sucks. I'm not only talking about complicated emacs macros but even the most basic are not supported like C-e for the end of the line or C-a for the beginning of the line.

Can somebody help to activate macros?

Comment: should I migrate the question to stack overflow?if yes somebody tell me!

Comment: Please accept your own answer to prevent this question from being bumped to the front page by Community again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I asked the question on stack overflow I am able to give a proper answer...

on Mac OS:

for the shortcuts:
you can go to Preferences -> Keymap and edit the shortcuts

for macros:
Preferences->Editor->Macros

Also there is a template "which are pieces of predefined code or text that can be generated by entering an abbreviation in the editor and then hitting tab."

thanks to Arnold Spence who answered on stack overflow...